# Classes Converter

Tags: jsf

Tenho estudado a programação em `JSF`, li que para que objetos sejam transformados em `String` é preciso um Converter para a entidade.

Existe uma classe já pronta e adaptamos as nossas Entidades? Como funciona ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar uma classe que implementa a *interface* `Converter`, nela podemos definir como se dará a conversão dos dados, desta forma vc personaliza esta conversão.

Por passos:
Crie uma classe que implementa a interface `javax.faces.contert.Converter` e é anotada com `@facesConverter`. Um conversor é uma classe que pode transformar  `strings` em `objetos` e `objetos` em `strings`, para isto esta classe deverá implementar os métodos `getAsObject()` e `getAsString()`;

O método `getAsObject()` deve converter de `String` para `objeto`, neste caso pode lançar uma exceção do tipo `ConverterException`;

O método `getAsString()` deve converter de `objeto` para `String`.

Respondendo sua principal dúvida, ao implementar `Converter` vc só precisará aplicar a lógica de conversão aos métodos.

Comment: Show, obrigado.

Comment: Legal: só uma dica... leve em consideração que essas classes podem inchar seu projetos, então aconselho a separa-las em pacotes distintos. Nos demos do Primefaces tem uns exemplos  legais.http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml, vá em `ThemeConverter.java`

Comment: Minhas entidades ficam no Modelo, onde os Converters devem ficar ?

Comment: Cara, depende. Eu costumo coloca-las em sub-pacotes de onde meus `Beans` estão, mas veja como melhor ficaria ao entendimento do seu Projeto.